# ggplot: set a time range for facets plotting based on date

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I just want to look at the trend (i.e., Y) in a time series dataset from 7am to 9am everyday.

Do you know how to plot it in ggplot?

Each subfigure in the ggplot facet shows the trend Y from 7am to 9am each day (2010/1/1 to 2010/1/14).

Here is my dataset:

```
  DateTime <- seq(as.POSIXct("2010/1/1 00:00"), as.POSIXct("2010/1/15 00:00"), "min")
  Y <- rnorm(n=length(DateTime), mean=100, sd=1)
  df <- data.frame(DateTime, Y)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- dplyr::filter(df, format(DateTime, '%H:%M:%S') < '09:00:00', format(DateTime, '%H:%M:%S') > '07:00:00')

df$Day <- format(df$DateTime, '%d')

plt <- ggplot(df, aes(DateTime, Y)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~Day, ncol = 2, scales = 'free_x') +
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = rel(0.7)))

print(plt)
```

[image: Output Image]

Comment: Is that `filter` from `dplyr`?

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I didn't mentioned.

Comment: In my opinion this only works for very consistent data. I have two days of timestamps and want to do a histogram with the x-axes the same. This answer relies on `scales = "free_x"` as much as the filtering (remove it to see what happens). Let's say data was missing but you still wanted to show 07:00-09:00... it wouldn't work. Try doing `df <- df[90:nrow(df), ]`, re-plot, and look at Day 01: it's all stretched out.